# Single Object content with handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have been using ember for a few days now, but i ran to this simple problem:
I made an ajax call and return the results to the model in the route. Basically the call will return a single json object. As i read in the guide, the model will be sent to the 'content' of the controller as below. The problem is how to get the data printed to the template? This is not working:

The Controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
content: [{name:'smith', age:'20',lastname:'jonnie'}]
});
```

Handlebars:

```
<p>{{name}}, {{age}}, {{lastname}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content` property is an array, so you rather loop over it to get your items out

### template

```
<ul>
  {{#each item in controller.content}}
    <li>{{item.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

or try something like this:

### IndexController

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  content: [{name:'smith', age:'20',lastname:'jonnie'}],
  firstObject: Ember.computed.alias('content.firstObject')
});
```

### template

```
<p>{{firstObject.name}}, {{firstObject.age}}, {{firstObject.lastname}}</p>
```

[Working example.](http://jsbin.com/ociVOro/2/edit)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you IP! the Ember.computed.alias('content.firstObject') is brilliant.